Interpretation of the result of an expression
Most Python textbooks and introductory tutorials I have seen say that

The result of every expression is some object.

But I have also seen several Python sources that say that

The result of every expression is a reference to some object.

After some googling, I came to the conclusion that the second quote is true for CPython if we treat the term "reference" as a "PyObject* pointer". As this post says (in the context of CPython):

Python's runtime only deals in references to objects (which all live in the heap): what goes on Python's stack (as operands and results of its bytecode operations) are always references (to values that live elsewhere).

My question is this: can we say that the phrase "the result of every expression is a reference to some object" is true in the Python language in general?
(i.e., can we say that this phrase is not just a CPython implementation detail, it is true for every Python implementation; of course, the specification of the term "reference" depends on the implementation)
And, if the answer is yes, why do most textbooks just say "the result of every expression is some object"? (i.e. they don't talk about references)

@Barmar But can we say, for example, that a Python variable is an object? Most people just say that it is a reference to an object, but not an object.

What's the distinction you think it makes? When you do a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a, you can say that a and b contain the same list or references to the same list.

@Barmar I have read that variables are references to objects (implemented in CPython as PyObject* pointers with a "name" string attached to them) and they have no type. Whereas Python object must have a type (in CPython, Python object corresponds to some "instance" of a C struct derived from PyObject struct and lives on the heap). So I am still not sure that "reference to object" and "object" are synonyms.

They're synonymous to Python programmers. All this stuff you're talking about are implementation details, not something exposed as part of the language.

@Barmar What about this quote from the official reference: "Some objects contain references to other objects; these are called containers. Examples of containers are tuples, lists and dictionaries. The references are part of a container’s value". This article clearly distinguishes between the concepts of "object" and "reference", and it doesn't say that this is a CPython-specific implementation detail...

It's not distinguishing between objects and references, it's distinguishing between containers and atomic objects. E.g. integers don't contain anything but their own value, while lists and dictionaries contain other values.

@Barmar Well, I think if they don't distinguish between "object" and "reference" here, they should just write "Some objects contain other objects; these are called containers" - it's just much shorter that way. While in the CPython implementation it is significant that each container object contains references to other objects (PyObject* pointers to them) and not objects themselves (not "instances" of structs derived from PyObjects).

Some authors use "reference" to make it clear that copies aren't made.
